# Как осуществить подзапрос SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется две таблицы: **ВОПРОСЫ** И **ОТВЕТЫ**:

**ВОПРОСЫ**

---

ID_ВОПРОСА **(PK)**
ТЕКСТ ВОПРОСА
ОТВЕТ **(FK)**
ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ **(FK)**

---

**ОТВЕТЫ**

---

ID_ОТВЕТА **(PK)**

ТЕКСТ ОТВЕТА
ID_ВОПРОСА **(FK)**

---

Как возможно реализовать такой запрос?

```
INSERT INTO ВОПРОСЫ (ТЕКСТ ВОПРОСА, ОТВЕТ, ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ) 
VALUES ("ТЕКСТ ВОПРОСА", ПОДЗАПРОС(СОЗДАТЬ ЗАПИСЬ В ТАБЛИЦЕ ОТВЕТЫ И ОТДАТЬ ЕГО ID), 1)
```

Вероятно, ход мыслей неверный. Но я прям и не знаю как иначе. Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: @strangeqargo MySQL 5.6. ну, если я правильно вас понял

Comment: похоже на [XY-вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044).

Comment: да. учитывая что текст вопроса слегка гуглится, похоже, что кто-то (автор) или очень плохо слушал, или кто-то (лектор) очень плохо рассказывал

Comment: @user200192, одним запросом в MySQL не получится обойтись.

Comment: @jfs как бы там ни было, у меня в голове нет других мыслей как можно решить данную задачу, поэтому и прошу если не помочь, то хотя бы направить верный путь

Comment: @user200192, вам критично решить задачу одним запросом? Или можно несколькими?

Comment: @strangeqargo если гуглится, пожалуйста, натолкните. я даже не могу сформулировать

Comment: @cheops да нет, главное - решение) ну, если не решение, хотя б натолкните куда копать.

Comment: @cheops ты прав, кстати. я неправильно прочитал пример. одним запросом можно делать штуки типа `INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height)
     VALUES (SELECT(id FROM user WHERE name='John Smith'), 83, 185)`; (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30042338/5006740). P.S. вы уверены, что вам надо одним запросом, а не одной транзакцией?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Схематично порядок работы с таблицами может выглядеть следующим образом

```
-- Сначала вставляем вопрос
INSERT INTO ВОПРОСЫ (ТЕКСТ ВОПРОСА, ОТВЕТ, ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ)
VALUES ("ТЕКСТ ВОПРОСА", NULL, NULL);

-- Получаем идентификатор вопроса
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- Вставляем ответы
INSERT INTO ОТВЕТЫ (NULL, "ТЕКСТ ОТВЕТА", @id);
SET @answer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO ОТВЕТЫ (NULL, "ТЕКСТ ОТВЕТА", @id);
SET @answer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO ОТВЕТЫ (NULL, "ТЕКСТ ОТВЕТА", @id);
SET @answer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO ОТВЕТЫ (NULL, "ТЕКСТ ОТВЕТА", @id);
SET @answer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- Обновляем FK ВОПРОСЫ.ОТВЕТ 
UPDATE ВОПРОСЫ
SET ОТВЕТ = @answer_id
WHERE id = @id;

-- Вставляем правильный ответ
INSERT INTO ОТВЕТЫ (NULL, "ТЕКСТ ПРАВИЛЬНОГО ОТВЕТА", @id);

-- Получаем идентификатор правильного ответа
SET @answer_right_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- Обновляем FK ВОПРОСЫ.ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ 
UPDATE ВОПРОСЫ
SET ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ = @answer_right_id
WHERE id = @id;
```

При реальном использовании русские названия столбцов и таблиц, следует заменить на английские эквиваленты, не содержащие пробелов.

Comment: не ясно, как id ответа в таблицу вопросы попадает? (или подразумевается, что после каждого `insert`  выполняются запросы аналогичные показанным запросам для правильного ответа?) Можно конечно, схему поменять (если нет специальных нужд, то лучше нормализованную схему использовать), чтобы добавление ответа не требовало UPDATE.

Comment: Согласен, не ясно, что вообще должно быть в поле ВОПРОС.ОТВЕТ, я оставил это поле не заполненным. Сам бы заводить такое поле в таблице не стал.

Comment: в данном случае ВОПРОС.ОТВЕТ должно содержать id из соответствующей записи в ответах также как и для правильного ответа. То есть ваш ответ не подразумевает, что mysql делает что-то магическое и автоматически заполняет ВОПРОС.ОТВЕТ foreign key, при создании записи в ОТВЕТЫ таблице с соответсвующим ВОПРОСЫ.id и поэтому не хватает запросов, чтобы заполнить ВОПРОС.ОТВЕТ колонку.

Comment: @jfs, ОПРОС.ОТВЕТ должно содержать id какой из 5 записей из таблицы ОТВЕТ, соответствующих данному вопросу? Каково в вашем понимании назначение этого поля? Я если честно, выслушал бы версию автора, но если вы хорошо понимаете его задумку, пожалуйста объясните.

Comment: как я уже сказал, схему следует изменить, но если использовать, приведённую схему, то следует заполнять поля, чтобы симулировать псевдо-запрос из вопроса (даже если это бессмысленно (не поможет автору вопроса решить настоящую проблему)—это может показать будущим посетителям "как осуществить подзапрос sql"). Можно самый последний id ответа помещать или даже для каждого ответа новую запись в вопросах создавать (опять таки—бессмысленно, но показывает как связанные sql запросы создавать)

Comment: @jfs, поправил ответ. Я если бы честно схему тоже изменил, но, user200192 не просит помощи в формировании схемы, поэтому работаем с тем что есть.

Comment: согласен, нужно отвечать на вопрос как поставлен, хотя конечно стоит кратко упомянуть другой подход, который более подходящий для решения действительной проблемы (но это уже другой вопрос).

Comment: @cheops спасибо огромное. и извините за мою нелогичную таблицу, начинаю ведь только во всем этом разбираться:)

Comment: @user200192: не за что извиняться—все начинают где-то. Вы задали вопрос, выразив желание научиться—это уже плюс. Если не получается схему поправить, то опишите своими словами какие запросы вы хотите над сохраненными данными выполнять, какие проблемы с текущей схемой (на ваш взгляд) и задайте это как отдельный вопрос. Почитайте о [нормальных формах, чтобы знать что это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).